# programmaticaly inject parameters on application startup in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I need to load init parameters from an external properties files through a service i already have.
this part is Tested , but i'm struggling to inject my init params on application start and make them accessible to the whole application. should i use an applicationScoped managed bean ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IF you want to work with ManagedBean
>
> Eager Application-Scoped Beans Managed beans are lazily instantiated.
>   That is, that they are instantiated when a request is made from the
>   application.
>
> To force an application-scoped bean to be instantiated and placed in
>   the application scope as soon as the application is started and before
>   any request is made, the eager attribute of the managed bean should be
>   set to true as shown in the following example:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girch.html

Answer (score 2):

Create an EJB Startup Service

```
@Startup
```

> The introduction of singletons also provides a convenient way for EJB
>   applications to receive callbacks during application initialization or
>   shutdown. By default, the container decides when to instantiate the
>   singleton instance. However, you can force the container to
>   instantiate the singleton instance during application initialization
>   by using the **@Startup** annotation. This allows the bean to define a
>   @PostConstruct method that is guaranteed to be called at startup time.
>   In addition, any @PreDestroy method for a singleton is guaranteed to
>   be called when the application is shutting down, regardless of whether
>   the singleton was instantiated using lazy instantiation or eager
>   instantiation. In lazy instantiation, the singleton isn't instantiated
>   until it's method's are first needed. In eager instantiation, the
>   singleton is instantiated at startup time whether or not it gets used.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

@PostConstruct
private void startup() { ... }

@PreDestroy
private void shutdown() { ... }
...
}
```

> If you are in a clustered environment this probably will not work for
>   you out of the box. This only works within a single VM. You will have
>   your StartupBean called on every server instance starting up or
>   shutting down. If you have special cluster requirements (e.g. only
>   initialize once for the complete cluster) you have to think about
>   synchronizing your StartupBeans by using a database. Usable on any EJB
>   3.1 compliant container and highly portable. This even should work with the lightweight Java EE 6 Webprofile

https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/a_sampling_of_ejb_3